# Why does Succubus kiss me?

Tags: vindictus

Sometimes when I'm fighting the succubus boss, she keeps kissing me. She sits down and kisses me. Why does that happen to me?

Comment: You know what Succubi are, right?

Comment: I said the boss succubus

Comment: I would reiterate Jason's comment.  This is like asking why a vampire is trying to bite your neck.  (Just to be clear, the answer to that question is "Because that's just what they do")

Comment: why it looks like kissing when biting your neck

Comment: @MinecraftGamer See the answer posted below, it explains what a succubus is.  Shinrai was using an analogy, a succubus is not a vampire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [succubus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succubus) is generally a creature of legends. A demon that takes the form of a woman and seduces men - for, depending on the lore, different motivations.

In the case of Vindictus, [the Succubus](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Succubus) in the game can indeed perform an action that very closely matches this:

> Casts a charm on the player, forcing them to collapse. She then mounts her prey and caresses their body, dealing damage while placing Drained Energy on her opponent.

In conclusion, the Succubus just does what a succubus does: It tries to seduce the opponent as a battle technique.